# Making instances of Neural Net and training them for different learning rates using a for loop. The second instance onward always gets stuck

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm doing Stanford's CS231n. Trying to understand why the following is happening. Here is the code. Data is of shape (49000, 32, 32, 3).

```
from cs231n.solver import Solver
from cs231n.classifiers.fc_net import FullyConnectedNet
from cs231n.data_utils import get_CIFAR10_data

data = get_CIFAR10_data()
for k, v in list(data.items()):
  print(('%s: ' % k, v.shape))

best_model = None
best_val_acc = -1
hidden_dims = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
reg= 0.0
std= 1e-2
learning_rates = [1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6, 1e-7]
for lr in learning_rates:
    model = FullyConnectedNet(hidden_dims, reg= reg, weight_scale= std, normalization= None)
    solver = Solver(model, data, num_epochs = 10,
               batch_size = 200, update_rule= 'adam',
               lr_decay = 0.95,
               optim_config= {
                   'learning_rate': lr,
               },
               verbose = True, print_every= 1000)
    solver.train()
    val_acc = solver.check_accuracy(data['X_val'], data['y_val'])
    if val_acc > best_val_acc:
        best_val_acc = val_acc
        best_model = model
        best_lr = lr
    del model
    del solver
print("Best learning rate found to be: ", best_lr)
```

The issue is that the first instance, i.e., `lr = 1e-4` works fine but from the second instance onwards the code execution proceeds very slowly.

This is not an issue of learning rates because I have tried different values of `'learning_rates'` and the `learning_rates[0]` always proceeds fine, but it gets very slow with the following `learning_rates` no matter what the actual values are.

I added some `print()` statements in the `Solver()` class to try to debug it. With `lr[0]` everything proceeds nominally. But with `lr[1]` onward each statement inside `Solver.train()` just seems to be executing slower.

My conjecture is that as the second instances of `FullyConnectedNet()` and `Solver()` come into the memory, the first instances are still there along with all the parameters and maybe that is causing the slow-down in code execution. I'm not sure how to test it though.

Edit: What I want to know is how do I execute all the models in one `for` loop rather than running them one by one separately? I'm not looking for good learning rates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in the implementation of the `FullyConnectedNet()` class. Instead of copying a list, I assigned it to another then made changes to it because of which the `1st hidden layer` got to the size of 3072` which lead to all the slowdown.

Such a basic mistake. But I've learned some lessons.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time here.

Answer (score 0):

The learning rates employed in `learning_rates = [1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6, 1e-7]` are extremely low, it's not strange that the training takes too much time for a normal PC. The value of `learning_rate[0]` is itself way lower than the values usually employed in various handbooks I checked.
(For example, I have Géron's book *Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow* in my hands right now, and the learning rate value employed is usually 0.01)

If what you need is to understand how to implement and train a neural network then you don't really need those specific values, I suggest you to raise the learning rates (e.g.: `[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4]`) and check how that impacts the model's performance.

Instead, if you really need to stick with that vector of learning rates, perhaps it's better to execute all the model versions one by one, so that your PC doesn't get overloaded.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know, how do I execute them in one `for` loop? 

I know that the learning rates are low, but they are not my problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with how Gradient Descent work? If you imagine cost function as some contour on 3d graph, gradient descent takes small steps towards global minimum. Learning rate tells how big these steps are.

You are using very small learning rates, therefore it is completely normal for any 
gradient descent to run slow. Here in code you're using Adam optimization which will speed up learning, but you also set learning rate decay which will lead to even smaller learning rates in later epochs. If your training set size is really large I would expect this code to run slow for smaller learning rates.

I'm not familiar with cs231n libraries, if they aren't optimized for parallel computing, you could try training different models on different threads? That will speed up overall execution time, however gradient descent for smaller learning rates will still take time to execute depending on how big your training size is, even though you're using mini-batches.